# Is there a black list in some company?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, human-resources

Two years ago, I applied for a position in a big company (international, and head of an industry) and was successful. However, based on some reasons (I replied to them that I had chosen another company), I rejected the offer.

Now I would like to apply again, however, after a few applications, I have not even received the first round notification interview invitation

Is it possible that I am in a blacklist?

Comment: Are you just applying to the same company, or the same position/team again?

Comment: Where was the job listing? If it's a 3 day old job listing on indeed.com then your applying for the same job would be strange but if you applied to them through website.com/careers it's possible that they just don't have any current openings. It's also possible that the job requirements have changed some and you're not as competitive a candidate as you had been before

Comment: Possibly, but if it is the case, it is not your fault based on what you describe. You did the correct thing, which is take the best offer available to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible that I am in a blacklist?

Yes.

Many companies track candidates and there is often a check box for "consider for other roles?" which can say either yes or no. Some companies do this, others do not.

This would depend a lot on how your last interaction went and if you manage to seriously annoy someone in the process. Personally, I prefer the decision to be mostly made before making a real offer: Creating a formal offer can take a lot of work, time and administrative effort, and I prefer not to do this if there are still open issues that can kill the deal. I would indeed be annoyed having an offer be rejected after giving the impression that everything is hunky dory. Whether that would result in blacklisting would depend very much on the details.

In any case, you will not be able to find out whether you got blacklisted and, even if you are, there is nothing you can do about it. Just keep applying, but make sure you cast your net wide enough and don't focus on a single company. Not having heard back on any application is unfortunately pretty normal these days.

Answer (score 4):

It's company specific whether you are or not, but it's certainly a likely scenario if you are qualified and there is no other reason to ignore you. You wasted company time and resources in the past, many companies would note that down.

Comment: How is rejecting an offer "wasting company time and resources"? That would be the equivalent of me never applying to a company again because they didn't offer me a job after inviting me to an interview.

Comment: Also disagree. Not being successful, either as a candidate or as a company hiring, is part of the process. Unless someone acted rude or something like that, I see no reason for problems there. They had a better offer, good for them. Now they want to come to us and we already know a good deal more about them than a random new candidate, good for us. Of course, there might be individuals who hold a grudge, but that would be highly unprofessional.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz while it's fine to disagree, the fact is that multiple applications have been ignored. I'm only answering based on the scenario posed in the question. If you can think of another reason that isn't included in my answer, please share.

Comment: There's a ton of reasons why an application gets ignored. Different people responsible, no job openings, etc. Can be an unprofessional person holding a grudge, sure, but as a company policy it would be pretty stupid.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz well, I've seen many policies over the years, this is one of them. Stupid or not hasn't been my call.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Hiring is a long term thing for big companies. It's more or less like dating. I blind dated a woman. I like her and like to develop a long term relationship. She said no. Okay. A couple of years later, she comes back and says can we have a dinner date? I say no because I don't think she likes me, otherwise, she would say yes in the first place. Do you think I am stupid?

Comment: @Peter: What matters is how you attribute blame on "wasting" time. Which is precisely what I've done with a company who required three interviews over the course of two months, after which they informed me of clear no-gos that they could have pointed out in the first meeting (such as a zero tolerance on working from home under any circumstance) when I explicitly raised those questions/expectation in that first meeting. They wasted my time and I've therefore blacklisted them. It's just that personal blacklists are not as written down or enshrined in the same way that a company blacklist is.